# Отоборажение контетнта с другого сайта

Tags: php, парсер

Есть необходимость отображения данных с другого сайта. Пугуглив нашел скрипт /
Ввел свои данные. И ничего не работает.

```
   <?php
// с кодировкой возможны проблемы, поэтому если вдруг появятся каркозябры, попробуйте добавить следующую строчку кода 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// сторонняя страница сайта, с которой будем брать контент. 
$content = file_get_contents( 'https://www.sute. ru');

// определяем начало необходимого фрагмента кода, до которого мы удалим весь контент
$pos = strpos($content, ' <div> ');



// находим конец необходимого фрагмента кода
$pos = strpos($content, '</div>');

// отрезаем нужное количество символов от конца фрагмента
$content = substr($content, 0, $pos);

//если в нужном контенте встречается не нужный кусок текста, то его вырезаем
$content = str_replace('текст, который нужно вырезать','', $content); 

// выводим необходимый контент
echo $content;
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что делаю не так?

Comment: представьте что вы инженер и ваша задача отравить ракету в космос. Вот вы нашли в инете инструкцию в которой написано "взять ракету, установить на стартовый стол, залить керосин,кислород,перекись, и запустить". Хватит ли вам этой инструкции, чтобы в реальности решить задачу?

Comment: доменов не бывает с пробелами в названии

Comment: Изучите тему парсинга.